# Sagemaker memory leak

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I deployed a deep learning model in the sagemaker and created a endpoint.
Unfortunately, I put it a large size image then the endpoint return  'RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory'.
So I would like to re-launch the endpoint, but seems there is not any restart button.
What could I do for restarting it?

Thank you

Comment: Endpoint status is 'InServise' but after that I put large image file results in 'RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory'. If I couldn't free GPU memory I need to delete the endpoint and recreate it, but it takes several times.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant UpdateEndpoint by "restart", you will not be able to update a SageMaker endpoint if it is already in 'Failed' status. This is documented in SageMaker [API references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_DescribeEndpoint.html#SageMaker-DescribeEndpoint-response-EndpointStatus).

If you have already identified the cause of endpoint failure, you can delete the failed endpoint and create a new one with the correct model.